# cannot locate properties file in java path

Tags: java, properties, path

My code cannot locate the .properties file where i have stored login information.

I have put the file in the src folder to make sure it compiles, and it does correctly.

below is the current location of the file and how i am trying to access it.

I have tried various different paths but no luck.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code that you are using to retrieve the properties file?

Comment: ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("properties/readme");

Comment: A constraint of this is that this program will be packaged up into an executable jar and the .properties will need to be edited so i assume it will need to be in the root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code;

```
 ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Selenium/readme");
```

to

```
 ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("readme");
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't compile a `.properties` file, you use it as is.

If you use a FileInputStream it will use the working directory which is set in your Run configuration (most likely the top directory)

But you are loading it as a resource which means it must be in your class path.  The simplest thing to do is to create a sub-directory for your configuration and add this to your programs class path.

Comment: I haven't used Eclipse for many years.  I suggest you do a search to find out how to create a directory and add it to your class path.

Answer (score 0):

Read properties file like:

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("src/properties/readme.properties"); //Or simply "properties/readme.properties"
```

Put readme.properties under `src/properties` directory.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("readme.properties");`

for more information read:

Answer (score 0):

I see that the .properties file is not inside the src folder. Also check the build path of your project.It will show you the src folders and the output folders location. Once you build the project using eclipse build project option, make sure your properties file is now available in the output folder.